# Why is /boot accessible to the average user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, security

The /boot of Linux holds kernel and boot stuff.  These aren't the sort of data you'd want the plain user to have access to.  So why are they even readable by the regular accounts?  Is it some kinda technical limitation of the security model, or is there an actual valid logical reason why it must be world readable (Ubuntu1604)?  Personally I would feel "safer" if it were 700 instead.  I can't imagine any shell scripts other than installers needing access to /boot post boot and installers are run as root or sudo anyway.

Comment: system.map is needed for some compilation which can be made by user.

Comment: On the other hand, is there a valid reason to hide it? Other than paranoia.

Comment: The boot process is as important to the proper running of the system as the password of the root user.  But I'm no expert...

Comment: But you do not give out the password to the root user, nor do you grant write access to /boot. Nothing wrong in knowing that there is a user called root, or able to read /boot/ .

Answer (score 2):

Why should it not be?  There's nothing sensitive in the `/boot` of most Linux machines.  It's just the same as allowing everyone to read `/usr/lib` or `/bin` or any number of other directories on the system.

The thing I'd be worried about is if non-privileged users could *modify* files there, as that would give them more direct access to privilege escalation via booting a special backdoored kernel or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Xiong Chiamiov's answer is good but I'd like to emphasize another aspect of the subject. (My answer is general, not limited to accessing `/boot/` only.)

> These aren't the sort of data you'd want the plain user to have access to.

Well, often I'd want to. Allowing regular users to read almost anything is a great support for them when they wish to *learn* about Linux. Let's suppose I'm logged in as such a regular user.

- Even with `root` access possible (say, on my own system), I can wander around directories as a regular user, read configs and scripts, compare them to manuals or online articles. I don't have to worry I break something due to a misclick or some other accident. If I need to change anything at the end, then I use `sudo` for this one thing only.
- Without `root` access (on somebody else's system) I may be interested in how the admin set things up so they work in such-and-such way.